# Firebase Database Invalid Path error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');


search.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var rootRef = firebase.database().ref(`https://challenge6-6b1d0.firebaseio.com/messages`);

console.log(rootRef);


})
```

Hello there I keep getting this validation.js:282 Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "https://challenge6-6b1d0.firebaseio.com/messages". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

I feel like its an easy fix but I have tried '', "" and `` with no luck and I keep getting this same error. I am also following the firebase docs on how to query.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database

Comment: You need to import firebase using the instuctions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a Firebase URL you should replace `ref` to `refFromURL` as pointed in the reference you provided

Edit: Now I see. The doc gives a wrong example to `refFromURL` :/

Comment: That worked, had no idea the documentation use ref not refFromURL, good know! thank you!